# How to search for specific string under a certain column in shell

Tags: regex, shell

Suppose I have a .csv file and if I were to open it up in excel it would look something like

```
 Bob     Jane     Alice
 blue    blue     yellow
 red     yellow   yellow
 blue    blue     red
 .        .        . 
 .        .        . 
 .        .        .
```

And so forth. So suppose I am only interested in the "Alice" column, and I want to search for how many "yellow"s are under Alice, how can I do that?

```
 grep yellow | wc -l
```

This would look for how many yellows there are and count the number of lines. However, how can I extract the Alice column before I count up the number of yellows?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple command where I am assuming that the .csv file uses "," as a delimiter.

```
 cat <file> | cut -d, -f3 | grep yellow | wc -l
```

If you do not know which column you want but know the name you could use something like this.

```
 export column=`head -1 <file> | sed 's/Alice\(.*\)/,/' | tr -dc ',' | wc -c`
 cat <file> | cut -d, -f${column} | grep yellow | wc -l
```

Comment: But what if I don't know which column "Alice" is? I know it's in the file but I don't know if it's the 3rd column.

Answer (score 1):

Select your desired column using awk, you can easily extend the procedure and supply the name (Alice in this example) as a variable to awk.

```
awk -F' *' '{
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { 
        if ($i == "Alice") {
            ix=i         
        }         
    } 
    print $ix 
}' <file> | grep yellow | wc -l
```

This should work.

Note: this awk call assumes the fields are separated by an undefined amount of spaces. Change `awk -F' *'` to `awk -F','` if fields are comma separated.